# How can I affect PATH in a makefile variable? Why is my example not working?

Tags: path, makefile

At the beginning of a makefile I have this line :

```
PATH := $(PATH):/other/dir
```

and this gives this error: `Recursive variable 'PATH' references itself`. What do I have to do so it works?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

GNU make (and many others) has two main ways of assigning values to variables. They differ according to the operator which you use. According to [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors), a single equals sign (`=`) will cause a *recursive expansion* of the value, whereas a colon-equals (`:=`) will cause a *simple expansion*.

Your quoted code uses a `:=` and so *should* cause a simple expansion. What you are seeing is an error message associated with a recursive expansion. I would expect that sort of error if you had something like this:

```
PATH = $(PATH):/other/dir
```

Could the error be being caused by a different line in your makefile which you *haven't* quoted? If you're sure that your cut-and-pasting is correct, and that it is this line which is causing the problem, it would be helpful if we could see the whole, unedited makefile.

Comment: I tried every way I could think of to add new folders to the path, while retaining the ones already existing. No luck. Finally, I settled on hardcoding the needed directories in the PATH.

Comment: @Geo , if you didn't understanc and try what Tim suggested, it doesn't make his answer incorrect and not worth accepting.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is to use the shell function:

> PATH = $(shell printenv PATH):/other/dir

Answer (score -7):

try changing $(PATH) to ${PATH}