# Make not finding executable added to PATH in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I'm having an issue with `make` and PATH that I don't understand. Here's a self-contained demo of the issue where `make` fails unexpectedly:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d ~/makeTest ]; then 
    rm -r ~/makeTest ;
fi
mkdir ~/makeTest
cd ~/makeTest
mkdir bin
echo "#!/bin/bash
echo Hello world!" > bin/install.sh
chmod +x bin/install.sh

echo ".PHONY: install

export PATH := \$(HOME)/makeTest/bin:\$(PATH)

install:
    @which install.sh
    @install.sh" > Makefile

make install
```

(View [on GitHub](https://github.com/levon003/scratchpad/blob/main/boneyard/demonstrateMakeIssue.sh).)

To summarize, this script produces a `bin` folder containing an `install.sh` script and a Makefile with the following contents:

```
.PHONY: install

export PATH := $(HOME)/makeTest/bin:$(PATH)

install:
    @which install.sh
    @install.sh
```

`make install` produces the output:

```
/Users/Suriname0/makeTest/bin/install.sh
make: install.sh: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Why does `which` correctly see the install.sh script on PATH but actually executing the command fails with "No such file or directory"? It's easy to verify that PATH is updated correctly: adding `@echo $(PATH)` produces the expected (updated) PATH.

Thank you for any help understanding this PATH issue!

Might be related to [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102786/makefile-cannot-find-executable-no-such-file-or-directory) weird PATH [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605623/how-can-i-affect-path-in-a-makefile-variable-why-is-my-example-not-working). On Mac OS.

Comment: Is there a `/bin/bash` in that environment? What if you use `#!/bin/sh` in the script? The `which` command is finding the script, but make cannot run it.

Comment: @Kaz you're welcome to try the script yourself; if it does work on your system please let me know. The problem is not the presence of /bin/bash (hence "No such file or directory"), and /bin/sh does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly for me:

```
$ cat bin/hello
#!/bin/sh
echo hello, world
$ cat Makefile
export PATH := $(PWD)/bin:$(PATH)

$(info $(PATH))

all:
        @hello
$ make
/home/kaz/junk/makepath/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/kaz/bin:/home/kaz/bin
hello, world
```

So the `export PATH :=`  assignment is clearly taking effect, allowing the recipe command `hello` to be found in that directory.

This is Ubuntu 18, with:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for i686-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

There is a discrepancy in the question in that the script which generates the Makefile uses `:=` but the snippet shown uses `=`.  That is actually not possible; GNU Make will diagnose if a `=` variable refers to itself recursively:

```
Makefile:1: *** Recursive variable 'PATH' references itself (eventually).  Stop.
```

If I comment out the `PATH` assignment so that `hello` is not found, the error looks like this:

```
$ make
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/kaz/bin:/home/kaz/bin
make: hello: Command not found
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

I also tried reproducing it via an almost identical script, which generates the directory with the script and the Makefile and immediately calls `make install`. I never see the error; `hello world` is always printed:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d mktest ]; then
    rm -r mktest ;
fi
mkdir mktest
cd mktest
mkdir bin
echo "#!/bin/bash
echo Hello world!" > bin/install.sh
chmod +x bin/install.sh

echo ".PHONY: install

export PATH := \$(PWD)/bin:\$(PATH)

install:
    @which install.sh
    @install.sh" > Makefile

make install
```

I would recommend using a system call tracing utility like `strace` to capture how `install.sh` is being accessed and what system call executed by what process is failing.

It's possible this is a problem in your specific version of GNU Make. For instance, the following bug affected a newer version that I'm testing with:

https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?56834

When this was fixed, a test case was added to make sure that a `PATH` set in the Makefile takes effect.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the actual answer, and would explain why I was was so confused. I tried on a Ubuntu 18 LTS server and verified that the script does succeed, running `GNU Make 4.1, Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`. The failure I observe is on Max OS Ventura, running `GNU Make 3.81, built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0`. I also corrected the typo in the Makefile excerpt.

Comment: Wow, 3.81? I wonder if it was [this](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?25662) bug, fixed between 3.81 and 3.82.    The bug I quoted is newer than 4.1; it seems to be a regression in the same area due to supporting `posix_spawn`.  The bug report in this one has a repro test case in which it manipulates `PATH` and something is not found. It's on Windows.

Comment: @Suriname0 : Just a design question: Why don't you simply set the PATH from the outside, i.e. `PATH="$PWD/bin:$PATH" make install`?

Comment: @Kaz Good find. I'm assuming I installed `make` via Mac's Command Line Tools, no idea why the version used is so old.  @user1934428 that's basically the work-around I went with: I fail the directive and tell the user they need to add the installed utility to PATH in whatever way they want!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a bug or limitation of Gnu Make 3.81, which is the version that Apple ships with its OS (`/usr/bin/make`). The behavior was changed in version 3.82, and it appears (in my limited testing) that version 3.82 and later execute the OP's script without error. However, 3.81 was the last version to be distributed under GPLv2, and Apple has shown a firm resistance to shipping anything licensed under GPLv3 (such as `make` 3.82 or `bash` v4), so I would never expect Apple to ever ship an updated version of Gnu Make. If they were to ship a newer `make` utility, I would expect them to use a different fork of Make altogether, as they did by replacing `bash` with `zsh` as their default terminal shell.

In Gnu Make 3.81 (Apple's `make`), changes to `PATH` affect the shell, but do not affect `make` itself. If a recipe is a straightforward invocation of a command, `make` does not launch a shell and have the shell look for it and launch it, `make` launches the command itself, searching for it ***using the `$PATH` it was launched with***. In this scenario, your changes to `PATH` are ignored.

For example, with this Makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/sh

TESTDIR = /tmp/testdir
export PATH := $(TESTDIR):$(PATH)

.PHONY: all prepare internal shell clean

all: prepare shell internal clean

prepare:
    @mkdir -p $(TESTDIR)
    @cp /bin/date $(TESTDIR)/mydate
    @chmod +x $(TESTDIR)/mydate

# This recipe forces `make` to invoke a shell by using command substitution
shell: prepare
    @echo "In target: shell"
    @printf "mydate is %s\n" "$$(mydate -I -u)"
    @echo "End target: shell"

# This is invoked directly by `make` and does not pick up the change in PATH
internal: prepare
    @echo "In target: internal"
    mydate -I -u
    @echo "End target: internal"

clean:
    rm -rf $(TESTDIR)
```

You will find that `make shell` works, but `make internal` does not.

```
$ make
In target: shell
mydate is 2024-02-02
End target: shell
In target: internal
mydate -I -u
make: mydate: No such file or directory
make: *** [internal] Error 1
```

The solution, if you want to be compatible with the default version of `make` you will find on Apple computers, is to force `make` to launch a shell. That can be as simple as chaining lines together using `; \` or using the `:` no op with `&&`:

```
install-workaround-1:
    @which install.sh; \
    install.sh

install-workaround-2:
    @: && install.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the changes you made to the path do not affect the shell. In order to work around this, I propose a couple of changes:

## #1 Indirect make

```
.PHONY: install install2

export PATH := $(HOME)/makeTest/bin:$(PATH)

install:
    which install.sh
    $(MAKE) install2

install2:
    install.sh
```

I don't like this approach because of the indirect nature of it.

## #2 Specify the relative path

```
.PHONY: install

install:
    ./bin/install.sh
```

This is the solution that I see in years of working in development teams. I like this solution because it does not tamper with the path, which could cause unwanted behaviors.

## #3 Modify the path in the shell

```
.PHONY: install

install:
    export PATH="${PWD}/bin:${PATH}"; \
    install.sh
```

This method works, too. But again, I don't like it because it tampers with the path as in solution #1. However, if the bin dir contains many executable, then this solution works better than solution #2.

Comment: I don't want to use the second and third solutions because I misrepresented my use case: one of the make directives installs a general tool to `~/.local/bin`, but copy-pasting that path the 20+ times the command in question appears in various directives seems horrible.  The first solution works... but literally _why_ does it work? It completely boggles my mind that it works.

Comment: Adding: thank you for the comprehensive response!